# Angular 6 *ngFor display different styles for first, odd, even and last

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular6

I am learning Angular 6 and just trying to put togheter some of the stuff I have learned and I am currently running into an issue that I cannot find an answer to. I am trying to change the style of a LI using *ngFor depending if the index is First, Last, Odd or Even. So far everything works but I can't figure out how to do it for the Last because everything I add a new object to my list, it is obviously the last so it render the color for the last.

I understand how to do it but the real problem is that I am adding stuff dynamicly to my list from a form and I'm not sure how to evaluate the Last so that the others become to right color.

Keep in mind that I am still a newb and it might look messy and I also understand that some client-side validations I am doing are probably not optimal or required since HTMl5 but I made it to learn.

Here is my code for my component HTML

>

```
<h1>List of courses :</h1><br>
<div *ngIf="courses.length > 0; then coursesList else noCourses"></div>

<ng-template #coursesList>
  <h2>List of Courses :</h2>
  <ul *ngFor="let course of courses; index as i;">
    <li [ngStyle]="{'background-color':getColor(i)}" style="color: white;">
      <strong>Index : </strong>{{i}} <strong>ID : </strong>{{course.id}} <strong>Name</strong> : {{course.name}}
      <button (click)="onRemove(i)">Remove</button>
      <button (click)="onModify(i)">Modify</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #noCourses>
  <h5>There are no courses in this list. Use the form bellow to add some.</h5>
</ng-template>

<div (keyup.enter)="onAdd()">
  <span>ID : <input type="number" (keypress)="checkNumber($event)" [(ngModel)]="fields.id" placeholder="Enter an ID"></span>
  <span>Name : <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="fields.name" placeholder="Enter a NAME"></span>
  <button (click)="onAdd()">Add</button>
  <button (click)="onClear()">Clear</button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="isNotNumber" style="background-color: red; color:black"><strong>ID can only be numbers !</strong></div>
<div *ngIf="noValues" style="background-color: red; color:black"><strong>Please fill all fields !</strong></div>
<div *ngIf="noModifyValues" style="background-color: red; color:black"><strong>To modify enter all informations!</strong></div>
```

Code for .TS

>

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent {
  noValues: boolean;
  noModifyValues: boolean;
  isNotNumber: boolean;
  fields: Courses = {id: null, name: null};
  courses: Array<Courses> = [];
  viewMode: string = null;

  checkNumber($event) {
    if ($event.keyCode != 13) {
      isFinite($event.key) ? this.isNotNumber = false : this.isNotNumber = true;
    }
  }

  onAdd() {

    if (!this.fields.id || !this.fields.name) {
      this.noValues = true;
    } else {
      this.courses.push({id: this.fields.id, name: this.fields.name});
      this.fields.id = null;
      this.fields.name = null;
      this.noValues = false;
    }
  }

  onRemove(i) {
    this.courses.splice(i, 1);
  }

  onClear() {
    this.courses = [];
    this.fields.id = null;
    this.fields.name = null;
    this.noValues = false;
  }

  onModify(i) {
    if (!this.fields.id || !this.fields.name) {
      this.noModifyValues = true;
    } else {
      this.courses[i].name = this.fields.name;
      this.courses[i].id = this.fields.id;
      this.noModifyValues = false;

    }
  }

  getColor(i){
    if (i % 2 === 0 && i != 0){i = 'odd';}
    switch (i) {
      case i = 0 : return 'orange';
      case i = 'odd' : return 'blue';
    }
    return 'red';
  }
}
interface Courses {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

[Image of the code in action for better understanding.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwHno.png)

Comment: If you only want cange the background-color you can use [style.background-color] and you can use ternary operator in the .html, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
getColor(i){
    if (i % 2 === 0 && i != 0){i = 'odd';}
    if (this.courses && (this.courses.length - 1 === i)) {i = 'last'}
    switch (i) {
      case i = 0 : return 'orange';
      case i = 'odd' : return 'blue';
    }
    return 'red';
  }
```

Hope it works - Happy coding !!

Comment: You can use it as `else if` in case to avoid another condition :)

Answer (score 7):

If you only want change the background-color you can use [style.background-color] and you can use ternary operator in the .html

```
<ul *ngFor="let course of courses; let index=i;
                                   let odd=odd;
                                   let last=last;
                                   let first=first">
    <li [style.backgound-color]="first?'orange':last?'purple':odd?'blue':'red'">
          ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's one good way to do it, I wanted to do it this way first but I didn't know you could use more than 1 condition in a short IF on a bind like that. By the way, is there a difference in performance with either ways? I understand this is just a style tho but what if we have ALOT Of values

Comment: If you has a lot of values, you can use [className]="first?'class1':... where 'class1', 'class2' are style defining in your component.css. In perfomance a ternary opertor is always faster. I prefer not make a call to a function, but I'm not sure about performance

Comment: thanks for your input. I will defenitly look this up.

Comment: It looks so insanely weird to people when I set *last = last* and I've been questioned whether I know what I'm doing. The optics of the syntax tells them that *last* already is declared in the scope and needs not be re-assigned, let alone to a variable of the same name. I showed them what happens if I don't assign *last* to *last* but the reaction was that *oh, you must've done a mistake elsewhere, this ain't looking right*. I don't want to be a cocky SOB and create infectious atmosphere. Got a link explaining to non-angulars why this is so in a non-angular'ish terms?

Comment: @KonradViltersten, pehafs the best way to see is the own docs when talk about structural directives https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#inside-ngfor (it's like another *ngTemplate, $implicits is the variable we use in the *ngFor="let **variable** of array, and odd, even, last, first others variables. Yes you asign variable in the "template" to functions defined in the *ngFor -well really are getters function -you can see the source in github https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts.

Comment: A good link about all of this is A good link about *ngFor is https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-ngfor-template-element. But I don't know if is waht are you looking for

Comment: @Eliseo I'll give it a try. However, I'm not hopeful. The problem is that individual X believes that they're sufficiently skilled to know the stuff or at the very least to recognize what they're not sufficiently skilled to talk about. And them not trusting me is the basis for the conclusion that I'm confused. Regardless the evidence. It's like when people argue that Java and C# are similar because they share most of the syntax. Well, then Swedish and Turkish are similar languages because they share most of the alphabet...  Thanks, anyway.

Comment: It's like a normal function. Inside a function getDistance(int velocity,int time){..} you use the name of the variables, e.g. {return velocity*time} For use the function you need pass this variables. in c# -well in any language- you pass values call the function like getDistance(3,4) or velocity=3;time=4;distance=getDistance(velocity,time).

Comment: The way to "pass the variable" to the template in Angular is let-variable=value, if you don't write let-velocity=velocity, inside the template you has no variable "velocity". Well, normally we use the same name of the variable, it's "natural" call the function as above, not a=3,b=4;distance=getDistance(a,b) in the same way that you can write let a=last;let b=first and use {{a}} and {{b}} but looks more natural use as name of variable last and first. Well really is a simplify but i don't know how explain me better

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rahul. The part I was missing is evaluating if there is something in courses. However, I had to had a few more lines to Odd and Last as follow :

> 

```
getColor(i){
    if (this.courses && i != 0 && (this.courses.length - 1 === i)) {i = 'last'}
    if (i % 2 === 0 && i != 0 && i != 'last'){i = 'odd';}
    switch (i) {
      case i = 0 : return 'orange';
      case i = 'odd' : return 'blue';
      case i = 'last' : return 'purple';
    }
    return 'red';
  }
```

Quick question. It seems like a whole lot of IF and && and checking specific things. Is that the way to do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

You could use if else ladder instead of mixing up if else and switch and assignments like given below

```
getColor(i)
{
  if(this.courses)
  {
  if(i==0)
      return "orange";
  else if(i==this.courses.length-1)
      return "purple";
  else if (i%2==0)
      return "red";
  else
      return "blue";
  }
}
```

Comment: Would def make a cleaner and easier to understand code. Thanks for your input.

Comment: When you have simpler alternatives, don't mix up and always welcome :)